# Disable SSLv3 on Tomcat 6.0.37 32-bit

Tags: tomcat, 32-bit, sslv3

I'm trying to disable SSLv3 on Tomcat 6.0.37 32-bit.  I can disable it on the 64-bit version using this line in the server.xml:

```
sslProtocols = "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
```

Is there a way to do it on the 32-bit version?

Comment: I imagine a quick google search would yield some useful results

Comment: I think this is a better question for: [http://serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com)

Answer (score 1):

The configuration quoted in the question isn't valid for any current connector with any current Tomcat versions on any current platform. And I doubt it was ever valid.

The configuration for 32-bit Tomcat and 64-bit Tomcat is exactly the same.

Configuration does vary between Connectors and there have been some changes to attribute names between Tomcat versions as consistency was improved.

Assuming you are using the default BIO connector with Tomcat 6.0.37 then what you want is:

```
sslProtocol="TLS" protocols="TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1"
```

For full details see the POODLE article on the Tomcat wiki:
https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Security/POODLE